# Configuring Eclipse+PyDev to upload to GAE without asking for password all the times with two step verification

Tags: python, eclipse, google-app-engine, google-authentication

I am working on a Google App Engine app with Eclipse 4.3 + PyDev 3.2.

The first time I upload the app on an Eclipse session it asks me for email address and password. My gmail account is setup with the 2 step verification, so I need to create an application-specific password every time. The new password lasts for the whole Eclipse session, but the next day I need another password.

Is it possible to configure it so that it is a trusted applicatoin/computer as I did with the Google App Engine Launcher and other applications?

EDIT 1:

I just noticed a message in the console that asks me for email and password. The message points me to this page.

Is it possible to configure Eclipse + PyDev to add the `--oauth2` option?

EDIT 2:

I found out how to use the `--oauth2` option suggested by marcadian's comment in Eclipse:

- Start the upload
- Increase the size of the window, so the Cancel button becomes visible
- Click the Cancel button
- Add the `--oauth2` option to the command string
- Click the Run button

Unfortunately Eclipse doesn't remember the command string editing, and at the next upload I have to manually add the option again.

So the alternative is between creating one app specific password at each Eclipse session or going through the 5 steps above at each upload.

Still the question is open: how to configure Eclipse + PyDev (to remember) not to ask for credentials?

Comment: Try to use --oauth2 option

Comment: @marcadian What's that? Where? How?

Comment: I'm not using eclipse or pydev, but there might be a feature to be able to customize the deploy command. Or you made your own script and call it from eclipse.